# ASP MVC Grid Nonfactors - add new row to grid table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nonfactors-mvc-grid

i am looking for a some way to add dynamicly row in grid based on framework nonfactors. I dont found any solution in internet.

Here, i have a some example to create grid in view

```
@(Html
    .Grid(Model)

    .Build(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(model => Html.TextBox(nameof(SysRecord.RecId),model.RecId)).Css("hidden");
        columns.Add(model => Html.TextBoxFor(x=>model.Name)).Titled("Name").MultiFilterable(true);
        columns.Add(model => Html.TextBoxFor(x=>model.Nip)).Titled("Nip").MultiFilterable(false);
    })
    .Attributed( new { url = Url.Action( "CrudAction","Company") } )
    .MultiFilterable()
    .Filterable()
)

<button id="mvc-grid-create" > create </button>
<button id="mvc-grid-update" > update </button>
<button id="mvc-grid-remove" > remove </button>
```

And the question it is how to create a row using jQuery? 
i can use .append or after('  '); but this solution needs to fill html tag, whats i dont want. 
i can too clone the last row, but what if none exists?

i found a few solution in google, but none works: 
for example, using method on data grid (.js) .addRow() and .addNewRow()

sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

The grid you are working with is purely server side so it doesn't have methods like `addRow` or `addNewRow` which are available in client side based grid. So your options are limited to appending raw html or changing the grid library.